# Pivot Table with Visual Studio 2010 C#

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, pivot-table

I have been looking for some examples to **create a Pivot Table** using another sheet with data ... but I can't find a good example.
Can you recommend me one? I have seen this: [Example Pivot Table](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.XLS/Spire.XLS-Program-Guide/Pivot-Table-Create-Pivot-Table-in-Excel-with-C-/VB.NET.html)

I'm new with this and I getting some errors and I can't advance...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I want to know if you try the code in the link you provided. If so, what error do you get? If not, please try it first.

Comment: Hi @JackJJun-MSFT I tried, and I get this error: Method not valid in this Context in this line -> PivotCache cache = workbook.PivotCaches.Add(dataRange);

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code in the link you provided, but it works for me. Therefore, you can refer to

the code I write.

Code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
        workbook.LoadFromFile(@"D:\1.xlsx");
        Worksheet sheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
        sheet.Name = "Data Source";
        Worksheet sheet2 = workbook.CreateEmptySheet();
        sheet2.Name = "Pivot Table";
        CellRange dataRange = sheet.Range["A1:D8"];
        PivotCache cache = workbook.PivotCaches.Add(dataRange);
        PivotTable pt = sheet2.PivotTables.Add("Pivot Table", sheet.Range["A1"], cache);
        var r1 = pt.PivotFields["ID"];
        r1.Axis = AxisTypes.Row;
        pt.Options.RowHeaderCaption = "ID";

        var r2 = pt.PivotFields["Description"];
        r2.Axis = AxisTypes.Row;

        pt.DataFields.Add(pt.PivotFields["OnHand"], "SUM of OnHand", SubtotalTypes.Sum);
        pt.DataFields.Add(pt.PivotFields["OnOrder"], "SUM of OnOrder", SubtotalTypes.Sum);

        pt.BuiltInStyle = PivotBuiltInStyles.PivotStyleMedium12;
        workbook.SaveToFile("D:\\PivotTable.xlsx", ExcelVersion.Version2010);
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("D:\\PivotTable.xlsx");
    }
```

Also, I simplified the xlsx file.

[image]

Finally, I get the following result.

[image]